# jQuery jqTransform plugin input width

Tags: jquery

I'm using jqTransform plugin and I have problem, when I add jqTransform plugin I can't
chanage input width, if I not use plugin all is ok.

## HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <form class="jqtransform">
        <div class="label">Vardas Pavarde<span class="z">*</span>:</div>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" value="Vardenis Pavardelevicius" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="field-submit field"><input type="submit" value="Siusti" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>                     
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#content form .field { float: left; width: 534px; height: auto; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 11px 0; }
#content form .field input[type="text"] { width: 1000px; }
#content form .field textarea { width: 524px; height: 105px; }
#content form .field-submit { text-align: right; }
#content .form-done { margin: 0 0 15px 0; color: #5f2d82; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are being wrapped in `div`s so you have to edit the `div`s.  You can do it programmatically, but the documentation itself says you should change their CSS.

http://www.dfc-e.com/sites/theme/jscripts/vendors/jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css

Their rendered HTML looks like this, as you can see you need to change the `jqTransformInputWrapper` if you want your input to enlarge:

```
<div class="rowElem">
    <label for="inputtext"">Input Text:</label>
    <div class="jqTransformInputWrapper jqTransformSafari" style="width: 210px; ">
        <div class="jqTransformInputInner">
            <div>
               <input type="text" name="inputtext" class="jqtranformdone jqTransformInput" style="width: 226px; ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, there some nice CSS libraries out there like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) that accomplish this type of form manipulation in a much more elegant and efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
 .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul{ 
 font-size:10px !important; 
  width:175px !important;} 

 .jqTransformSelectWrapper{
 width:175px !important;
 }
```